# CSS Grid: Why do my sections that supposed to be below are moved up to the upper rows here?

Tags: css, grid, css-grid

I'm trying to set up a grid with CSS and for some reason the elements that I defined to go into lower rows are getting merged into run above this way:

[image: image with current grid layout]

My code on the main element:

```
  #block-container {
    border: 1px solid steelblue;
    width: 50%;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 20%);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas: 
      "header header header header header"
      "break-setup break-setup . session-setup session-setup"
      "................ timer timer timer .................."
      ".......... .......... buttons ............ ..........";
  }
```

And other elements:

```
#title {
  grid-area: header;

  border: 1px solid magenta;
}

#break-setup-container {
  grid-area: break-setup;
  border: 1px solid magenta;
}

#session-setup-container {
 grid-area: session-setup;
 border: 1px solid magenta;
}

#running-time-section {
  grid-area: timer;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#start-stop-buttons-container {
  grid-area: buttons;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Could you let me know why it happens and how could I fix it?

UPDATE:

I was actually able to make it work correctly in an isolated case with such grid layout, where I used HTML and CSS directly ([isolated grid](http://codepen.io/konstantinkrumin/pen/XWXYjeB?editors=1100)). Not sure why it is not working in my React setup

Comment: Have you tried to reduce your periods? One period signifies one empty grid cell. Looks like you had so many periods in your grid-template-areas.

Comment: yeah tried doing that now, but still stays the same. I think multiple dots just used to align each row and don't change actual layout

Comment: Could you also share some of your HTML code?

Comment: I have this app built in React with JSX. Here is my pen: https://codepen.io/konstantinkrumin/pen/RwryXgN

Comment: I was actually able to make it work correctly in an isolated case with such grid layout, where I used HTML and CSS directly (https://codepen.io/konstantinkrumin/pen/XWXYjeB?editors=1100). Not sure why it is not working in my React setup.

Comment: I understood now what was the issue, in the case with last 2 containers which I was trying to add to the grid they were not direct children of the grid and that's why it didn't work. It was violent parent-children rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that in my React JSX code I tried to add 2 last elements to the grid and they were not direct children of the parent `<div></div>`, therefore it was violating parent-children rule of the grid layout.

To fix it I had to add the parent container of the `#running-time-section` and `#start-stop-buttons-container` to the grid instead of each of them separately, and the arrange those elements individually inside that container